# Python: server side detect whether user is logged in to facebook (and not necessarily connected to my app)

Tags: python, facebook

is there a server side equivalent to the javascript api FB.getLoginStatus()
There seems to be something similar in the PHP SDK, but I don't want to use PHP. If it is possible in PHP it must be possible in Python - but does this mean I'd have to reverse engineer the PHP SDK to be able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this
`Python client library for the Facebook Platform` from https://gist.github.com/1190267

Then you can parse `signed_request` or parse facebook cookie written by `fb js sdk`:

sample code for parsing `signed_request`:

```
signed_request = pyface.parse_signed_request(request.POST['signed_request'], fb_app_secret)

if signed_request:
    if signed_request.has_key('user_id'): 
        facebook_user_id = signed_request['user_id']
```

Note: `pyface` the .py file where I put the code from above link